# How to remove a directory when the cron job is within the child directory

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I am new at Linux and I need to setup a script that after the work has been done using a cron job needs to delete the working directory.

The directory that I am in straight after the job is :

```
working/dealer/network/db/scripts
```

I am doing this within the job to delete this whole path:

```
cd ~/working

cd ..

rm -rf working
```

As I am new I am sure there is a better way of deleting the working directory and its subfolders.

Comment: is it working ? are you looking for a better way ?

Comment: I'm looking for a better way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your solution is fine. You could optimize the first to steps into one:

```
cd ~
rm -rf working
```